# Old sparsebundle has no volumes

Tags: mount, time-capsule, disk-volume, sparsebundle

I have old sparsebundle files on my Apple Time Capsule. I can't seem to mount them. Error I get is no volumes found. I can see package contents, and size on disk is 113.4 GB.

I've tried: `hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/Joy/<name>.sparsebundle`, however, that only loads as `/dev/disk2`, but against it it doesn't say `GUID_Partition_scheme` and there is no `/dev/disk2s1 Apple_partition_map` or `/dev/disk2s2 Apple_HFSX`.

I've also tried to use Migration Assistant, it shows the Time Machine sparsebundle, but it says no volumes.

Please advise. Can I create a new empty sparsebundle using `hdiutil -create`, and copy the package contents from the no volume sparsebundle to this new one? Any other ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't receive any reply ...

Anyways, I downloaded Disk Drill, and then managed to read the sparsebundle. It managed to recover the HFS+ partition also. Currently, recovering the entire folder to an external drive.